# Are Bovine serum albumin, Avidin, Ficoll-70 and Dextran-70 positively charged or negatively charged?

Tags: homework, proteins, biophysics

Bovine serum albumin, Avidin, Ficoll-70 and Dextran-70,are they
positively charged or negatively charged ? And which other solvents can be used as a substitute to water for preparing solutions in each case ?

Comment: What part is giving you difficulty. At least for the charges you can use Gooooooooooogle...

Comment: yes but mainly I require to know about the solvents.

Comment: Flagging because this is a bunch of unrelated questions. (each molecule should be its own question, solvents are also a separate question entirely) The question as is is unlikely to be useful for future users.

Answer (score 2):

For charge, you could check this one by sequence level, for example for Bovine Albumin (Uniprot: P02769) you can get the theoretical pI of 5.82, as the mean of pKa aminoacid values, to do this can use [protparm](http://web.expasy.org/protparam/), so when the pH > pI, the protein has a net negative charge and when the pH < pI, the protein has a net positive charge.

And there are only two organic polar solvents I known to work proteins, DMSO (pKa = 35) and
Dimethylformamide (DMF, pKa=-0.01 (20ºC))